# Custom Font display wrong with Font Awesome?

Tags: joomla, fonts, joomla3.0, font-awesome

I have a Custom Font, Roboto Light and Roboto Regular installed on a Joomla t3 Template.
when i add  Font Awesome Icon the custom Font not shown correctly:
in Firefox show as  a serif type
In Safari and Chrome the Roboto Light shown as regular or bold.
the same conflict shown also with glyphicon classes. 
May some can help me?

Link: http://kulimot.ch.mistral.ch-meta.net/index.php/de/entsorgungsysteme/ballenpressen.html

Answer (score 0):

From the link you've added to the question, it looks like you've done this:

```html
<td class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok">
    &nbsp;MACFAB-Abfallpressen können die Abfallmenge um bis zu 90% reduzieren
</td>
```

Although this is a glyph icon and not a font-awesome icon, you should probably not set that style on the `td` itself, but rather add an `i` element in the `td`. Something like this:

```html
<td>
    <i class="fa fa-folder-open pull-left"></i>
    &nbsp;MACFAB-Abfallpressen können die Abfallmenge um bis zu 90% reduzieren
</td>
```

P.S. This code uses a font-awesome icon instead of a glpyhicon.

Comment: Ok, but the icon not shown, in Firefox / Safari, and in Chrome is a blurred text

Comment: I checked your page again. It seems you now have an icon in place, BUT you now have the text inside the `i` element.

    <td>
        <span class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"> Aufgrund ihrer klar strukturierten und einfachen Bedienung sind sie sehr benutzerfreundlich</span>
    </td>

Answer (score 0):

I checked your page again. It seems you now have an icon in place, BUT you now have the text inside the `i` element. Your text is withinh the `<i>` opening and the `</i>` end tag. See the code I've copied from your page:

```html
<td>
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-4"> Sie benötigen nur wenig Platz</i>&nbsp;
</td>
```

If you do this, the text will take on the styling defined by the `i`. Basically it will use the fonts defined in those styles.

Luckily, the solution is simple from this point (I tried it on the code in your page, and it works for me). Just get the text out of the `i` element.

```html
<td>
    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-4"></i> 
    Sie benötigen nur wenig Platz&nbsp;
</td>
```

P.S. Not sure why the `&nbsp;` is there at the end of your text, you probably wanted it between the icon and your text. So move it to the front of your text.

Comment: Sorry it works only inside <i> </i> When i made it outside, save and return to code view, the class is deleted automaticily.

Comment: so i have the solution,i add a class validation, i[class] to the TinyMCE Editor plugin, now it works fine. Thank you